# hello i am a junior coder and programmer . what are the first step towards learning the beauty and function's of data science

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, lattice-crypto

"I really enjoy and would like to learn about cryptography. How and where to start? what programs did you first use, and support teams? I am learning lots of things which I should include in my projects".

Comment: Well, this is off-topic. Start with a good book as an Introduction Modern Cryptography, and online course as Dan Boneh. And, I saw that you are on Math too, strengthen your group theory, finite field, and probability is suits for you.

Comment: Hot meta post: https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/how-to-handle-i-want-to-begin-with-cryptography-but-i-dont-know-from-where-t?cb=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below links provide the idea behind cryptography:

https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/kb/how-to/introduction-to-cryptography

https://thebestvpn.com/cryptography/

https://www.garykessler.net/library/crypto.html

The examples is based on the language you are using like R, python etc. Anyway the steps and basics are same.